# How do I get the string of an element, not including the string's sibling element?

Tags: jquery

So I have this:

`<span class="a"> String <span class="b">Herp</span> </span>`

and I need to define span.a's string as a variable without getting span.b's string like:

`var a = $(".a").text();`

How should I do it?

Comment: Check this answer. This is what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery#answer-298758

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var a = $(".a")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/Hs9CT/)**

```
var txt1 = $(".a").contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3;
}).text();
```

---

or like:

```
var txt1 = $('.a')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

**[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/Hs9CT/1/)**