# How do I get the contents (inner html) of an element except the last and penultimate children?

Tags: jquery

So I have something like this:

`<span class="a"> Contents <span class="b">Herp</span><br></span>`

...where the **"contents" may vary from a *string*, to a *single image* to *multiple linebreaks***. I need to define the "contents" as a variable without getting the b.span and br.

How do you do it? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Hmm looks familiar ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091884/how-do-i-get-the-string-of-an-element-not-including-the-strings-sibling-elemen

Comment: "contents" may vary from a string, to a single image to multiple linebreaks -- I bolded this out. Yes, I did ask that question but I realized the contents are not strings all the time. So yeah, it needs a different code. =w=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) to get all the contents, then apply the [`.slice()` method](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) to slice off the last two:

```
$("span.a").contents().slice(0,-2)
```

Comment: Oh sorry, but it only works if the content is an element, not if it's a string. 8(

Comment: I tested it with just a string (copied and pasted exactly what was in your question) and it worked for me. Also worked when I inserted some img elements. http://jsfiddle.net/PLLhw/

Comment: But I need to get the html of those elements. Not just the text.

Comment: If I use html() instead of text(), it returns as null.

Comment: I would think you'd need to loop through the elements returned by the code in my answer and test each one to see if it is a text node or not, because I would guess `.html()` doesn't work on text nodes. Have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/PLLhw/1/ (Or just try `.html()` on each one and if it's null then assume that one is a text node and use `.text()` on it?)

Answer (score 1):

```
alert($('span.a').text()); //will alert 'Contents'
```

Comment: but will also get `span.b` with it.  The op wants doesn't want the `span.b` in the value.

Comment: "contents" may be an img, or string, or any element, so I need to define an exception. 8|

Answer (score 1):

```
var clone = $('span.a').clone();
$('span.b', clone).remove();
var text = clone.text();
console.log(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want everything except the last 2 items try:

```
var $content= $(".a").contents();

var htmlnodes = $content.filter(function(ndx) {
  return (ndx < $content.length -2);
});

    console.log(htmlnodes);​
```

Comment: "contents" may be an `<img>`, or string, or any element, so I need to define an exception. 8|

Comment: if its `any` element, then you really leave no identifier to check against.

Comment: `return (ndx < $content.length -2);` seems a little less complicated, though still rather more complicated than just using the `.slice()` method...

Comment: @Jawn Ive made an edit to my code, if you look at it now, it will return an array of htmlnodes, which you can then iterate through, or append to another node

Comment: @nnnnnn updated with your comment, your right, its a bit easier to read.

Comment: Cool. Note: you're not returning an "array" as mentioned in your earlier comment, you're returning a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

You can stick element A in a variable.

```
var $a = $('.a').children().remove();
alert($('.a').html().append($a));​​
```

In this example, we're not hard-coding the number of elements that should be removed or sliced or whatever. It's slightly more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

```
var c = $('.b').nextAll('br').remove().end().parent().find('.b').remove().end().html();
alert(c)
```

See it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/arvind07/XrbXJ/)

Comment: But won't that remove all br elements? OP said "contents" could include multiple line breaks.

Comment: @nnnnnn now it does not remove the line breaks in "contents".